# Java Identifying Source of Latency

Tags: java, performance, optimization, latency

I am working on a java process which is conceptually rather simple. It is a single thread constantly fetching data from various sources and making decisions based on these. I have recently noticed a suspicious delay between 2 log lines, where I would not expect much processing to happen between the 2. (Tens of milis delay vs expectation of a 1 to a few milis)

Since this suspicious delay is not always there, my first thought was that I did a poor job at minimizing the need for garbage collection, causing the JVM to pause execution at unwanted times.

While I still believe I did a poor job with that, it doesn't seem to be the cause. I have added the following JVM parameters: `-Xlog:gc*=info,safepoint::timemillis,level,tags`
and I see no pause between my suspicious log lines. Could there be other JVM pauses that these JVM params would not reveal?

Anyways, would java pros have any recommendations to try and efficiently track down the source of this latency? Any (preferably free) tools I could use to monitor and understand what's happening?

Environment info: Linux 3.10, java 11. The process in question is running on an isolated core, other than that I have not done much tuning.

Comment: Have you tried analysing your code with Flight Recorder + Mission Control?

Comment: Add more log lines.  Find the new two lines with the gap between them.  Add more log lines between those. Repeat.  It only takes a few iterations to narrow it down.  If the delay starts spreading out between many lines, then you've found a *bunch* of slow stuff.  If you get way more log lines that you expected, you found an unexpected slow loop.

Comment: it might also depend on how you log. a dedicated `Logger`? a `FluentBit` that parses logs? `System.out::println`?

Comment: @Eugene, good question. I am using `java.util.logging.Logger` instances

Comment: I have not looked too deep, but I do see that some of the things in that logger are done under a `synchronized` lock. That could explain it. May be also a File is rotated at exactly that time also

Answer (score 0):

depending on where the information is coming from, it may be latency in the grabbing of the information. like if it has to reach out to a server, then the connecting and querying of the server may be introducing that latency. or maybe you are accessing your disk too quickly, and you are limited by the speed of your drive. besides that, I am not sure. maybe add in some of these.

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
foo();
System.err.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time + "ms");
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, there is no connecting and grabbing the information. The logs are produced by the process who is doing the work directly into a file.